# Talend : tExtractRegexFields and globalMap

Tags: talend

My job is composed like that :

tRest >> tExtractJSonFields >> ttExtractRegexFields > (row3) > tMSSqlRow

I'm using a tExtractRegexFields compenent with 3 output variables.
The next component is a tMSSqlRow.
I would like to use tExtractRegexFields's output in my SQL query as a parameter.

My SQL Query is like that :
;WITH nums AS
   (SELECT 1 AS PAGE
    UNION ALL
    SELECT PAGE + 1 AS value
    FROM nums
    WHERE nums.PAGE < "+(Integer)globalMap.get("row3.lastpage")")
INSERT INTO flight.Calendar_Page (DT_CAL, NUM_PAGE)
SELECT '2016-01-01', PAGE
FROM nums
option (maxrecursion 32767);"

"row3.lastpage" is a tExtractRegexFields's output variable. 
This one is always contain NULL value.

I don't understand why globalMap.get("row3.lastpage") is null. Anyone knows how to use tExtractRegexFields's outputs ?

Thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use `globalMap.get("row3.lastpage")` in the SQL query in your `tMSSqlRow`, but simply concatenate `row3.lastpage` with your SQL string. And `row3.lastpage` is not a string, but `row3` is a Java class in the Talend generated code and `lastpage` is one of its fields. This field contains the data you want to inject into the SQL statement.

`globalMap.get("row3.lastpage")` will always by `null`.

Your query should be something like:

`WITH nums AS (SELECT 1 AS PAGE UNION ALL SELECT PAGE + 1 AS value FROM nums WHERE nums.PAGE < " + row3.lastpage + ") INSERT INTO flight.Calendar_Page (DT_CAL, NUM_PAGE) SELECT '2016-01-01', PAGE FROM nums option (maxrecursion 32767);`